# Issues trying to use Update and Create in a single function

Tags: laravel, crud

I want to create a row for one table, but update a column in another table, for this I'm using both `update()` and `create()`, but it keeps ending up in the same error, no matter how I put it down.

[image: See error here]

```
    public function createuserinfo(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        $userupdate = User::update([
            'status' => '1'
        ]);

        $infocreate = Personal::create([
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'first_name' => $request->first_name,
            'last_name' => $request->last_name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password,
            'address' => $request->address,
            'zipcode' => $request->zipcode,
            'city' => $request->city,
            'phone_number' => $request->phone_number,
            'ss_number' => $request->ss_number,
            'document_number' => $request->document_number,
            'license_number' => $request->license_number,
            'expiration_date' => $request->expiration_date,
            'employer' => $request->employer,
            'jobtitle' => $request->jobtitle,
            'contract' => $request->contract,
            'start_date' => $request->start_date,
            'general_practitioner' => $request->general_practitioner,
            'dentist' => $request->dentist,
            'health_insurance' => $request->health_insurance,
            'contact_one_name' => $request->contact_one_name,
            'contact_one_relation' => $request->contact_one_relation,
            'contact_one_address' => $request->contact_one_address,
            'contact_one_zipcode' => $request->contact_one_zipcode,
            'contact_one_city' => $request->contact_one_city,
            'contact_one_phone_number' => $request->contact_one_phone_number,
            'contact_two_name' => $request->contact_two_name,
            'contact_two_relation' => $request->contact_two_relation,
            'contact_two_address' => $request->contact_two_address,
            'contact_two_zipcode' => $request->contact_two_zipcode,
            'contact_two_city' => $request->contact_two_city,
            'contact_two_phone_number' => $request->contact_two_phone_number
        ]);

        return $userupdate . $infocreate . redirect()->route('users.details');
    }
```

I need it to redirect to the user details page and have their information added/altered. I hope someone will be able to help me with this problem.

Comment: Link is not working has slack is restricting access.

Comment: Also, what is the error you are receiving?

Comment: Give us your credentials to check the error ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try this

```
  public function createuserinfo(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    $userupdate = $user->update([
        'status' => '1'
    ]);

    $infocreate = Personal::create([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'first_name' => $request->first_name,
        'last_name' => $request->last_name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password,
        'address' => $request->address,
        'zipcode' => $request->zipcode,
        'city' => $request->city,
        'phone_number' => $request->phone_number,
        'ss_number' => $request->ss_number,
        'document_number' => $request->document_number,
        'license_number' => $request->license_number,
        'expiration_date' => $request->expiration_date,
        'employer' => $request->employer,
        'jobtitle' => $request->jobtitle,
        'contract' => $request->contract,
        'start_date' => $request->start_date,
        'general_practitioner' => $request->general_practitioner,
        'dentist' => $request->dentist,
        'health_insurance' => $request->health_insurance,
        'contact_one_name' => $request->contact_one_name,
        'contact_one_relation' => $request->contact_one_relation,
        'contact_one_address' => $request->contact_one_address,
        'contact_one_zipcode' => $request->contact_one_zipcode,
        'contact_one_city' => $request->contact_one_city,
        'contact_one_phone_number' => $request->contact_one_phone_number,
        'contact_two_name' => $request->contact_two_name,
        'contact_two_relation' => $request->contact_two_relation,
        'contact_two_address' => $request->contact_two_address,
        'contact_two_zipcode' => $request->contact_two_zipcode,
        'contact_two_city' => $request->contact_two_city,
        'contact_two_phone_number' => $request->contact_two_phone_number
    ]);

    return $userupdate . $infocreate . redirect()->route('users.details');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to update user without passing it's id which would surely give an error.

Try this:

```
public function createuserinfo(Request $request)
{ 
 $user = Auth::user();

 $userupdate = User::find($user->id);
 $userupdate->status = '1';
 $userupdate->save();

 $infocreate = Personal::create([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'first_name' => $request->first_name,
        'last_name' => $request->last_name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password,
        'address' => $request->address,
        'zipcode' => $request->zipcode,
        'city' => $request->city,
        'phone_number' => $request->phone_number,
        'ss_number' => $request->ss_number,
        'document_number' => $request->document_number,
        'license_number' => $request->license_number,
        'expiration_date' => $request->expiration_date,
        'employer' => $request->employer,
        'jobtitle' => $request->jobtitle,
        'contract' => $request->contract,
        'start_date' => $request->start_date,
        'general_practitioner' => $request->general_practitioner,
        'dentist' => $request->dentist,
        'health_insurance' => $request->health_insurance,
        'contact_one_name' => $request->contact_one_name,
        'contact_one_relation' => $request->contact_one_relation,
        'contact_one_address' => $request->contact_one_address,
        'contact_one_zipcode' => $request->contact_one_zipcode,
        'contact_one_city' => $request->contact_one_city,
        'contact_one_phone_number' => $request->contact_one_phone_number,
        'contact_two_name' => $request->contact_two_name,
        'contact_two_relation' => $request->contact_two_relation,
        'contact_two_address' => $request->contact_two_address,
        'contact_two_zipcode' => $request->contact_two_zipcode,
        'contact_two_city' => $request->contact_two_city,
        'contact_two_phone_number' => $request->contact_two_phone_number
    ]);

    return $userupdate . $infocreate . redirect()->route('users.details');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `static` call to `User` model, use the same object.

```
    $user = Auth::user();
    $updateUser = $user->update('status' => '1']);
```

Also, you can use the `save` method.

```
    $user = Auth::user();
    $user->status = '1';
    $user->save();
```

Reference [Eloquent ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent)

Answer (score 1):

You have laravel function for that  createOrUpdate().
And if you are updating row with update(), you need to specify what are you updating.

You want to update user with User::update() but Model does not know which user if you do

```
User::find(1)->update() or User::where('name', 'test')->update()
```

it would know.

or in your case

```
$user = Auth::user();

 $user->update([
    'status' => '1'
 ]);
```